# Delete empty cell in 2D array python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following 2d array

`[[0, 3], [3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [], [], [], []]`

What is the easiest way to delete the cell which doesn't have any item?

so after operation, the output will be

`[[0, 3], [3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do

```
y = [x for x in y if x != []]
```

if these are python lists.

If these are numpy arrays do:

```
y = list(filter(None, x))
print(y)
```

If this doesn't work please state the module you're using for the arrays as [they're not build in](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp).

Comment: This is a 2D array

Answer (score -1):

supposed that you want to create a new list that has only non empty elements

```
    y = [[0, 3], [3, 0], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [], [], [], []]
    newList = []
    for x in y :
      if x :
        newList.append(x)
```